# Embedding migrations with packr in golang

Tags: go, database-migration

I'm trying to create db migration in my golang app using embedding migrations with packr.
The folder structure in my project is:

[image]

Migration code in `sqlite.go` file

The migration code snippet is:

```
func (s Storage) Migrate() error {
    const op = "storage.sqlite.New"

    migrations := &migrate.PackrMigrationSource{
        Box: packr.New("migrations", "./migrations"),
    }

    _, err := migrate.Exec(s.db, "sqlite3", migrations, migrate.Up)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

When I run this code `migrate.Exec` always returns 0 migrations applied as result and no error

In other hand if I run this migration from cli

```
sql-migrate up
```

I got result

```
Applied 1 migration
```

And I can see changes in my db.

How to create migrations from my code?